# systemd service startup order, but only on bootup

Tags: services, systemd-unit

My use case is pretty similar to what is described [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403830/):

Lots of custom services, not dependent on each other. On boot, they all start simultaneously and cause a peak in CPU and RAM load.

What I want to do is set a specific order for these services to start up in, which is probably what the Before/After systemd unit options were invented for.

So far, this question is the same as the question linked above.

What I'm unsure of:

> Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied. i.e. if a unit is configured with After= on another unit, the former is stopped before the latter if both are shut down. Given two units with any ordering dependency between them, if one unit is shut down and the other is started up, the shutdown is ordered before the start-up. It doesn't matter if the ordering dependency is After= or Before=, in this case. It also doesn't matter which of the two is shut down, as long as one is shut down and the other is started up. The shutdown is ordered before the start-up in all cases. If two units have no ordering dependencies between them, they are shut down or started up simultaneously, and no ordering takes place. It depends on the unit type when precisely a unit has finished  invoked and they either failed or reported start-up success.

(Source: systemd.unit manpage.)

The catch is, **I only need any of the startup ordering to happen on bootup**.

Some of these services are started, stopped and restarted independently in an ad-hoc manner when the host is running, and all the ordering should not affect these operations. I.e. if I want to restart one of the services ordered with Before/After options, I only want to restart that particular service, and keep all the rest untouched.

Is After/Before still a good idea in this use case?

If After/Before applies to the ad-hoc start/stop operations too, then is there any other solution for this use case?